# Input and output in C

Tags: c, input, io

How to take some unknown number of integers from input and display them on the console?

The number of values will be given through console.

Comment: If you had taken the time to use the "search" box at the top right corner of the page, you would have found dozens of nearly duplicate questions.

Comment: And there's that new Google thing I hear about. Doesn't your instructional material say anything about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the prototype for main is:
main(void) or
main(int argc, char *argv[]);

This are the command line arguments of the program 
you can iterate through them with something along this lines

```
  int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i < argc; i++) {
         printf("%s" argv[i]);
}
```

Untested but should be enough to get you going.

Comment: This will work only if you pass integers as a command-line parameters.

Comment: sorry, I want the values to be entered during run time and the values should be stord in an array

Comment: Surely not it work sor anything on the command  line and no the command line arguments are "Strings" If you need an Array than it's something different but that does not follow from your original question...

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically allocate memory for the numbers using malloc.

```
int count=0;
scanf("%d",&count);
int* numbers=malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
//take integers from input here
free(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

normally your main method should look something like this

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

when you run the you program you will supply a number of arguments to it, say n numbers, so you will have n+1 arguments in total (recall that your program name is argument 0!). therefore you can do something like:

```
int* array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (argc-1));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++) {
    array[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
}
```

then you can do:

```
for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

sorry if there are any syntax errors

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Print one-by-one as you go (ignore the first: the number of numbers)

```
int main(void) {
    <READ_NUMBER>; // and promptly ignore it
    while (<READ_NUMBER>) {
        printf(<PRINT_NUMBER_JUST_READ>);
    }
    return 0;
}
```